# Proof that $\int f'(x)dx = f(x) + C$

Tags: calculus

If we define the antiderivative of a function $f$ as the function which when differentiated returns $f$ -- that is, let $g$ be the antiderivative of $f$, then $\frac {d}{dx} g(x) = f(x)$ -- how can we derive the fact that **all solutions** to the equation $y=\int f'(x)dx$ (this notation meaning $y$ is "the" antiderivative of $f'(x)$) will be of the form $y=f(x) + C$?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It follows from the fact that a function with zero derivative is constant.

So, if $F'(x)=G'(x)$, then $(F(x)-G(x))'=F'(x)-G'(x)=0$, so there is a constant $C$ such that $F(x)-G(x)=C$.

Comment: But, what if f is not absolutely continuous, e.g., the Cantor function? Then we can't recover f(x) from f'(x)?

Comment: My answer (nor thequestion) does not deal with the existence of antiderivatives. It deals with their uniqueness.